# YAML parse error, using Ruby psych

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

So I came across the YAML below and try to parse it using Ruby Psych, however, it outputs "found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at" the line 'checkboxesValues:'.(the 4th last line)

When I use notepad++ to open the YAML, the last 4 lines of the YAML are in red color.
But I can't find what's wrong with this YAML.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
-
title  : Multiple Radios Inline
fields : 
name:
  label  : Group Name
  type   : input
  value  : radios
label:
  label  : Label Text
  type   : input
  value  : Inline Radios
required:
  label  : Required
  type   : checkbox
  value  : false
radios:
  label  : Radios
  type   : textarea-split
  value  : [1,2,3,4]
radiosValues:
  label  : Radios Values
  type   : textarea-split
  value  : ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
-
 title  : Multiple Checkboxes
 fields : 
name:
  label  : Group Name
  type   : input
  value  : checkboxes
label:
  label  : Label Text
  type   : input
  value  : Multiple Checkboxes
required:
  label  : Required
  type   : checkbox
  value  : false
checkboxes:
  label  : Checkboxes
  type   : textarea-split
  value  : ["Option one", "Option two"]
checkboxesValues:
  label  : Checkboxes Values
  type   : textarea-split
  value  : ["1", "2"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `notepad++` click `Find`, select `Regex` option and search for `\t`. There should be none.
Also, enable displaying whitespaces (P-like looking icon) and search for anything inconsistent.

Comment: After I removed the tab escape, the red color gone. Many thanks.

Comment: It still looks like the indentation isn't quite right - does it parse properly now?

Comment: Yes, it parse now, after i removed all \t and the - at the 1st line.